# Access is denied error when initializing PostgreSQL DB on Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql

I'm on Windows 10. I downloaded the most recent version of Psql.

I was like:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin>initdb.exe "C:\psql_db"
```

> ```
> The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "Sean".
> This user must also own the server process.
>
> The database cluster will be initialized with locale "English_United States.1252".
> The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "WIN1252".
> The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
>
> Data page checksums are disabled.
>
> creating directory C:/psql_db ... ok
> creating subdirectories ... ok
> selecting default max_connections ... 100
> selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
> selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... windows
> creating configuration files ... ok
> running bootstrap script ... ok
> performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
> syncing data to disk ... ok
>
> WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
> You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
> --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
>
> Success. You can now start the database server using:
>
>     "pg_ctl" -D "C:\psql_db" -l logfile start
> ```

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin>"pg_ctl" -D "C:\psql_db" -l logfile start
```

And it was like:

> server starting
>
> Access is denied.

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: @Sean Reddy, did you find the solution?

Comment: Any solutions to this?

Comment: @YashGoenka yes

Answer (score 12):

I think you are trying to create the `logfile` inside `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin`, for which you don't have write permission

Specify something like `"pg_ctl" -D "C:\psql_db" -l "c:\users\joe\logfile" start`

Comment: this solution is woking. Thanks a lot.  Better keep the log file outside of your PostgreSQL install folder.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of windows file permissions. You can put the data folder on desktop "c:\Users\\Desktop\" instead of "C:\psql_db". Or maybe give your user more permissions.